# parsing pdf content stream to understand paragraph boundary

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, xpdf

Is there a way to parse the pdf content stream and identify paragraph boundary? I read ISO 32000-1:2008 but could not understand if, the pdf content stream contains any operator which tells a display software to start the paragraph, or end it. Can any text extractor software like `pdfbox` or `xpdf` provide that information?

Comment: PDF does not require you to mark paragraph beginnings or ends. You actually even need not have all parts of the same paragraph together in the content stream, you can put one word here, one letter there, etc. Text extraction software tries to find lines of text in reading order, maybe even tries to recognize multiple columns, but a generic approach to recognizing paragraphs most likely will fail pretty often.